# Single .dll with MEF

Tags: c#, plugins, reflection, mef

With reflection i can load a single dll.

```
Assembly testAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"c:\Test.dll");
```

But with MEF all the plugins in the directory are red.
Is there a way with MEF of doing the same ?

I can do this :

```
public IPlugn Load(string name)
    {
        return Plugins
          .Where(l => l.Name.Equals(name))
          .FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

but this is a based on the the whole list of plugins.

Kind regards

Dipke

Answer (score 2):

Catalogs are the mechanism MEF uses to find plugins - and they are very flexible.

You are presumably using a DirectoryCatalog?

If so, you can use the [overload of the constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833475(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes a search pattern:

```
var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog("C:\\", "Test.dll");
```

Alternatively, you can use the [AssemblyCatalog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.assemblycatalog(v=vs.110).aspx), which will allow you to just specify the assembly to use.

```
var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.LoadFile("C:\\Test.dll"));
```

Finally, if you want any really specific behaviour (load plugins from a web-service call, or crazy stuff like that), then you can just implement your own [ComposablePartCatalog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.primitives.composablepartcatalog(v=vs.110).aspx).